# How to process a function via background job using Bull and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, queue

I would like to know how to run code in my function 'myCustomMethod' via the Queue/Bull . Is this the right way to do it?

**./models/Sport.js**

```
export async function myCustomMethod(type, req)
{
    console.log("This method should be executed via the Queue / Bull");
    let computationResult = true;
    return computationResult;
}
```

**cronCustomFile.js**

```
import { myCustomMethod } from './models/Sport.js';

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', () =>
{
    var battleRoyaleQueue = new Queue('battle_royale_queue');
    console.log('Checking live events every 5 seconds');
    battleRoyaleQueue.process(function (job, done)
    {
        try
        {
            console.log('Processing via battle_royale_queue');
            myCustomMethod('live-events');
            done();
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Bull version
"bull": "^3.6.0"

**Additional information**

It looks like jobs are not being added to the queue or processed.
[image]

**Reference**

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are creating a worker to process a job every 5 seconds, but you are not creating jobs to be processed.  You should instead create the worker once, and then create a job that is added to a queue and processed repeatedly.

**config/bull.js**

```
import Queue from 'bull';
import { myCustomMethod } from '../models/Sport.js';

var battleRoyaleQueue = new Queue('battle_royale_queue');
battleRoyaleQueue.process(function(job, done) {
  const { type } = job.data
    try {
      console.log('Processing via battle_royale_queue');
      myCustomMethod(type);
      done();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  });
```

**recurringJob.js**

```
import battleRoyaleQueue from '../config/queues.js';

const beginReccuringJob = (type) => {
  battleRoyaleQueue.add({type: type}, { repeat: { cron: '*/5 * * * * *' } });
};
beginReccuringJob('live-events');
```